# How to add a white space between each column boxes

Tags: html, css

I just wanna ask how to add a white space between each column boxes. I've been trying to figure it out for the past hour but I was not able to find an answer. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
        <h2>Column 3</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 4</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 300px;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: You have 4 boxes each 25% wide, so they take up the whole width. If you want gaps, reduce the percentage accordingly.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using floats for this, instead of [multi-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts), [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Typical_Use_Cases_of_Flexbox) or [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) layouts?

Comment: Hello, yes unfortunately I don't know anything about multi-column, flex-box or grid layouts yet. I'm still new to web development so there's still a lot of stuff for me to learn. Thank you for providing the link, I'll definitely study it.

Comment: Well, if you take a look at my answer it should hopefully illustrate the concepts. In the meantime, though, please do read up about the concepts; they're far more powerful and useful than floats in contemporary browsers.

Comment: Be aware that dealing with float quirks is probably going to bring you much more trouble in the end than learning to do it properly with contemporary techniques. David is very right on this, I can not suggest any stronger to follow him on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using either CSS Grid or CSS Flex-box for your layout; either of those options will allow you to specify the `gap` (formerly `grid-gap`, but since changed to work with both Grid and Flex-box) between items; for example with Grid:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let source = document.querySelector('.row');
  [...source.cloneNode(true).children].forEach(
    (el) => source.append(el)
  );
});
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  /* triggers the use of CSS grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* defines four columns each of which is
     1fr - one fractional unit of the available
     space: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  /* defines a gap of 0.2em above and below each
     grid-row, and of 1em between adjacent grid-
     columns: */
  gap: 0.2em 1em;
  counter-reset: columnCount;
}

.column {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 300px;
  counter-increment: columnCount;
}

h2::after {
  content: ' ' counter(columnCount);
}
```

```html
<button>Add more content to the row</button>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
```

Or, with Flex-box; note that with flex-box the `gap` property doesn't take effect until the contents are sufficiently closely-packed that the `space-between` declaration of `justify` is insufficient to keep them separated:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let source = document.querySelector('.row');
  [...source.cloneNode(true).children].forEach(
    (el) => source.append(el)
  );
});
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  /* triggers the use of css flex-box layout: */
  display: flex;
  /* allows the content of the .row element(s)
     to wrap to new lines as required: */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* evenly spaces the child elements of .row
     across the available space (so, by default,
     the items are separated visually from each
     other): */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* when the children of the .row element are
     too numerous to be spread apart by the use
     of 'justify: space-between' the gap forces
     the gap between horizontal 'rows' of 0.2em
     and between 'columns' of 1em:  */
  gap: 0.2em 1em;
  counter-reset: columnCount;
}

.column {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 300px;
  counter-increment: columnCount;
}

h2::after {
  content: ' ' counter(columnCount);
}
```

```html
<button>Add more content to the row</button>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Multi-column is a little different and, currently, less easily used and styled for layout; but it does allow some appropriate customisation:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let source = document.querySelector('.row');
  [...source.cloneNode(true).children].forEach(
    (el) => source.append(el)
  );
});
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  /* setting a column-count property causes the browser
     to use a multi-column layout for the element, and
     the child elements of that element will be placed
     into the appropriate columns (though some fine-
     tuning may be required): */
  column-count: 4;
  /* sets a 1em gap between adjacent columns: */
  column-gap: 1em;
  counter-reset: columnCount;
}

.column {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 300px;
  counter-increment: columnCount;
}

h2::after {
  content: ' ' counter(columnCount);
}
```

```html
<button>Add more content to the row</button>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count).
- [`column-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap).
- [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
- [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).

Bibliography:

- "[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)."
- "[A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)."
- "[Basic Concepts of Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)."
- "[Basic Concepts of Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)."
- "[CSS Multi-column Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns)."
- "[When and How to Use CSS Multi-Column Layout](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/01/css-multiple-column-layout-multicol/)."